# Windows Server 2012 R2 fails to load Remote Desktop module in powershell

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, powershell

I have my citrix master image that i'm using to test a script meant for a staggered reboot for my target devices. Need to import remote desktop module for the script to work. For some reason i cant import the module and i checked for the module and it exists in the system32 folder.

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Comment: Are you importing it as an explicit file path, or implicitly by name?  When you say it's in the system32 folder, do you mean windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\modules\?   As @CoryKnutson asks, do you get an error?